# React Native - Unable to set state with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to call external api during the first time when the component is rendered and get the list of all countries with async/await function.  However I got empty state back after I called the setState function.  I'm quite new to RN and been stuck in this problem for days now.  Appreciated if anyone can help. Here's what I've been trying to do...

1. Call countryapi and get the country name and iso2 (only country name and iso2 are available in the response)
2. After that call I wanna get more details about that specific country, such as iso3 and country flag, so I passed the parameter iso2.
3. After I destructured for country, iso3, and country flag after the second api call, I called setState each time I destructured for that specific country.  However state is not getting updated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome } from "react-native-vector-icons";
import countryapi from "../src/countryapi";

const CountryScreen = () => {
  const [countryDetails, setCountryDetails] = useState([]);

  // Fetch country details { country name, iso3, iso2, country flag }
  const countrySearchAPI = async () => {
    try {
      const countriesData = await countryapi.get();
      const countries = countriesData.data;

      for (const country in countries) {
        const { iso2 } = countries[country];

        let countriesDetailsData = await countryapi.get(`/${iso2}`);
        let { name, iso3, emoji } = countriesDetailsData.data;

        setCountryDetails([
          ...countryDetails,
          {
            countryName: name,
            iso3,
            iso2,
            countryFlag: emoji,
          },
        ]);
        console.log(countryDetails);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    console.log(countryDetails);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    countrySearchAPI();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.searchSection}>
        <FontAwesome name="search" size={30} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Search for Country" style={styles.inputBox} />
      </View>
      {/* <FlatList
        data={countryDetails}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <Text>
              {item.countryName}
              {item.countryFlag}
            </Text>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      /> */}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is `console.log(countryDetails)` printing out anything?

Comment: console.log(countryDetails) is only returning "Array[]"

Comment: Print out countriesData, what does that return?

Comment: it returns the list of all countries [
  {
    "id": 101,
    "name": "India",
    "iso2": "IN"
  },
  ...
]